# Sticking two div simultaneously to window top using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this topic has been discussed here before but i am facing some difficulties with one of the problems already solved.
I want to stick TWO div(s) to the top at the same time. (E.g: When Layer2 sticks to the top, i want layer 2 to also stick to the top with a different height and width)
Currently I am trying to stick only ONE div but its not working.

HTML

```
<div id="Layer1"></div>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="Layer2"></div>
<div id="Layer3"></div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});

function sticky_relocate() {
    var s = $('#Layer2');
    var pos = s.position();

    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;

    s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + window_top);

    if (window_top > div_top) {
        s.addClass('stick');
    } else {
        s.removeClass();
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#Layer2 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0px;
    top: 276px;
    width: 950px;
    height: 57px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

I would like some help here and i would also like to know how should i stick two divs at the same time.
Thanks in advance.

**[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayan/vurttu4g/#share)**

Comment: Can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: I am afraid I am not well versed with how to make a fiddle.

Comment: Just go to http://jsfiddle.net and put in the minimum amount of code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ayan/vurttu4g/#share

Answer (score 0):

This is because of CSS [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

`#id` selector will always be applied with more importance, than `.class` selector.

Replace this

```
.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

With this

```
#Layer2.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

or this

```
.stick {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

See the whole thing here [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vurttu4g/1/)

P.S. I have changed the JavaScript slightly.